# How to get port number from sslstream in C#

Tags: c#, tcpclient, sslstream

I would like to get the portnumber from a sslstream in C#. 
When you have TcpClient you can extract this like:

```
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
var endpoint = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
```

Comment: [`endpoint.Port`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipendpoint.port?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hi, @Ibai. First fo all: I didn't do it (Downvote). Now, i think your answer should be complemented with more information about: Why used `TcpClient` instead of `sslstream`, as the question did. Usually, In SO, answers pass for an adicional process called Review, where members of Stack overflow review it and vote according the answer; Maybe, they made downvotingin at your answer. Check this link about answering questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 4):

`SslStream` is a "decorator" around another arbitrary `Stream`, in this case a `NetworkStream`. It doesn't expose the inner (tail) stream (well, it *does*, but `InnerStream` is `protected`), and `SslStream` itself has no concept of a port. Basically: you'll need to get this information *separately* to wrapping it in the decorator.